# Tensorflow Serving - more names for the same model

Tags: python, config, tensorflow-serving

I want to redirect two different URLs to the same model request, so that I don't need to create another `base_path` or version.
If I write my config file as bellow, does it cache my model twice?

**models.config**:

```
model_config_list {
  config {
    name: 'name1',
    base_path: '/models/model/',
    model_platform: "tensorflow"
  },
  config {
    name: 'name2',
    base_path: '/models/model/',
    model_platform: "tensorflow"
  }
}
```

Comment: Best way to find out is probably to try it? :)

Answer (score 0):

So I ran [this project](https://github.com/stefanprodan/dockprom) to watch over my Docker containers and started modelserving one model. Then I added the same model path and version as I described in the question, but with a different name.
The alocated memory for serving was near the double, and with three models it was near three times.